# Oracle SQL Developer different language date

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

In SQL Developer if I want to see sysdate in 'Bangla' language then do I need to use a UNICODE Bangla font? Here is my query and the result is like this:

```
select to_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-Month-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=bangla') "Bangla Date" FROM dual;
```

Result: `09-¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿-2016`

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your database support Unicode? Check with

```
SELECT * 
FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');
```

In case the characterset does not support unicode but the **national** characterset does, you could use

```
SELECT TO_NCHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-Month-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=bangla') "Bangla Date" 
FROM dual;
```

In any case you must select a font which is capable to display these characters. You can use this page to verify:  [Local Font List](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=09-%E0%A6%AB%E0%A7%87%E0%A6%AC%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%81%E0%A7%9F%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%80-2016), resp. [Font Support for Unicode Block 'Bengali'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/bengali/fontsupport.htm)